# Trying to label point in graphics by user input

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm having trouble with a CS project in Python and whenever I think I'm getting close to solving the problem.

```
win = GraphWin("Exercise 8 Page 119", 400,400)
for i in range(1):
    p1 = win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p1.setFill("black")
    p2 = win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    p2.setFill("black")
    line = Line(Point(p1.getX(),p1.getY()), Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY()))
    line.draw(win)
   
    # midpoint
    midpoint = line.getCenter()
    midpoint.draw(win)
    midpoint.setFill("cyan")


    import math
    # midpoint math
    yMid = p2.getY()+p1.getY()/2
    xMid = p2.getX()+p1.getX()/2
   # midpoint text
    midpointLabel = Text(Point(xMid+0.5, yMid+0.5), "midpoint is: " + "(" + str(xMid) + "," + str(yMid) + ")")
    midpointLabel.draw(win)
```

whenever I test it out the midpoint goes somewhere random, or I can't see it at all. I can't seem to place the coordinates close to the actual midpoint every time. These are the teacher's exact words "This program will have the midpoint labeled, offset slightly from the actual location of the midpoint of the line."

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: are you aware that your for loop only executes the code once?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem is a simple mathematical error:

```
yMid = p2.getY()+p1.getY()/2
xMid = p2.getX()+p1.getX()/2
```

which should be:

```
yMid = (p2.getY() + p1.getY()) / 2
xMid = (p2.getX() + p1.getX()) / 2
```

complete code:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Exercise 8 Page 119", 400, 400)

p1 = win.getMouse()
p1.setFill("black")
p1.draw(win)

p2 = win.getMouse()
p2.setFill("black")
p2.draw(win)

line = Line(p1, p2)
line.draw(win)

# midpoint
midpoint = line.getCenter()
midpoint.setFill("cyan")
midpoint.draw(win)

# midpoint math
yMid = (p2.getY() + p1.getY()) / 2
xMid = (p2.getX() + p1.getX()) / 2
# midpoint text
midpointLabel = Text(Point(xMid + 0.5, yMid + 0.5), "midpoint is: ({}, {})".format(xMid, yMid))
midpointLabel.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow that completely went over my head.